# Nethereum "WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."

Tags: go-ethereum, nethereum, c#

I'm trying to call a contract function from asp.net backend, using a public node.

```
            var abi = 
            @"[{""constant"":false,""inputs"":
[{""name"":""addr"",""type"":""address""},
{""name"":""amount"",""type"":""uint256""}],""name"":""test1"",""outputs"":
[{""name"":"""",""type"":""bool""}],
""payable"":false,""stateMutability"":""nonpayable"",""type"":""function""},
{""constant"":false,""inputs"":[{""name"":""addr"",""type"":""address""},
{""name"":""amount"",""type"":""uint256""}],""name"":""test2"",
""outputs"":[{""name"":"""",""type"":""bool""}],
""payable"":false,""stateMutability"":""nonpayable"",""type"":""function""},
{""anonymous"":false,""inputs"":
[{""indexed"":false,""name"":"""",""type"":""address""},
{""indexed"":false,""name"":"""",""type"":""uint256""}],
""name"":""Test1"",""type"":""event""},
{""anonymous"":false,""inputs"":
[{""indexed"":false,""name"":"""",""type"":""address""},
{""indexed"":false,""name"":"""",""type"":""uint256""}],
""name"":""Test2"",""type"":""event""}]";

        var account = new Nethereum.Web3.Accounts.Account("private-key-here");
        var web3 = new Nethereum.Geth.Web3Geth(acc, "http://104.236.182.85:30303");
        var contract = web3.Eth
.GetContract(abi, "0xcff863b8f953caf4418c50d56f2cc5afc839be01");
        var myFunction = contract.GetFunction("test1");
        var result = await myFunction
.CallAsync<bool>("d56F18bD24557E75E1b0082B66d6B9f5134Ed1da", 2);
```

And always I'm getting this WebException. Even when I'm just requesting my account's balance:

```
var balance = await web3.Eth.GetBalance
.SendRequestAsync("d56F18bD24557E75E1b0082B66d6B9f5134Ed1da");
```

Is there another ways to execute the contract function? Am I have to run my own node instead of public?

Node's port is opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the geth client initialization. It should be started with these arguments (rpc is most important):

```
geth --rpc --rpcaddr <ip> --rpcport <portnumber>
```

Probably the public nodes I tried to use didn't enable this. 
If you don't need you own node you can just use Infura. It's turned to be not just a REST API service as I thought before.

```
var web3 = new Nethereum.Geth.Web3Geth(acc, url: "https://mainnet.infura.io");
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize geth correctly and allow access to specific api's

```
geth --rpc <ip> --rpcapi eth,web3 --rpccorsdomain "http://localhost"
```

You have other APIs so make sure that you have started geth with the correct APIs enabled that you want to access with Nethereum.

Here is an example of the available APIs

```
{  
 "id":1,
 "jsonrpc":"2.0",
 "result":{  
  "admin":"1.0",
  "db":"1.0",
  "debug":"1.0",
  "eth":"1.0",
  "miner":"1.0",
  "net":"1.0",
  "personal":"1.0",
  "shh":"1.0",
  "txpool":"1.0",
  "web3":"1.0"
}
```

This parameter is useful if accessing the geth node from a browser, you can put "*" but I would not recommend it as it allows anyone to connect and manage the node.  If I am running geth locally and interacting with it locally I will use localhost or 127.0.0.1

```
--rpccorsdomain "http://localhost"
```